# Выделяется ли запятыми "до пули и ножа"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Прошлое ничего не стоит, когда до пули и ножа идёт проверка на прочность.**
"До пули и ножа" выделяется запятыми?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Прошлое ничего не стоит, когда до пули и ножа / идёт проверка на прочность.***

Это стихи?

Тогда сочетание лучше не обособлять. По смыслу оно  входит в основное сообщение (какая именно проверка),  ритмическая структура предложения также позволяет прочесть его без обособления.